# Can't get rigidbody collisions to work in Unity3d with box colliders

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, collision, rigid-bodies

so I am using Unity to create an Android game and I cannot get any collisions to work. Both objects have box colliders and one has rigidbody attached to it. When I hit play it just falls through the floor. So I instead tried to make the rigidbody object kinematic and control it's movement via transform.Transform instead of rigidbody.addforce I then made a cube in front of the character with a box collider that has "Is Trigger" checked. I then attached this script to both the rigidbody and the cube.

```
#pragma strict
function OnTriggerEnter ( block : Collider){

print("BA BAM!");
Destroy(block.gameObject);

}
function Update () {
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
    Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
}
}
```

but I will move the character right through the block and nothing happens!

I then decided to create a new blank scene and made two cubes. Both have box colliders. I dragged one above the other and added rigidbody physics to it. But it just falls through the other block when I hit play! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try to check both isTrigger

Comment: "When I hit play it just falls through the floor." Please make sure that (a) the floor has a collider attached, and (b) the objects in question are on [layers that collide with each other](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html). If you start with an empty project, then drop a Cube+Rigidbody onto a Plane, they should collide.

Comment: I havn't heard of the Layer-Based Collision Detection before... I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1):

Triggers aren't solid, so a box with a trigger and a rigid body would fall through a solid object. Generally the object with a rigid body should not be set to trigger, and stationary volumes should be set to trigger. Besides that, I tried your code and it works correctly. Are you sure you have this script applied to the objects that are colliding?

Comment: Yes, when the objects are falling through each other is when the triggers are off and I just have box colliders and a rigidbody plus collider on the other object

Comment: Should I reinstall unity? Or maybe Android physics work differently?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the object using the Translate function will teleport the object into a new Vector3 position instead of smoothly moving it.

Also, check which Physics layer each object is set to. Then, go to Edit -> Physics to edit which Physics layer can collide with each other.

Other than that I would speculate it would due to some bug in your installation of Unity.